# Stop Media Player After starting new intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, widget, media-player

Here's my problem:  I start a media player, and if I start a new intent, or leave the app and go back to it..

```
mp.stop;
```

..wont work (mp is my media player variable).

is there anyway to fix this?

Bonus to whoever can tell me how to link it up to a widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always must call `mp.release()` in your Activity's `onDestroy()`. It is also recommended to at least call `mp.pause()` in on `onPause()` Activity's method.

If you want playback to continue outside of Activity lifecycle (after `onPause()`/`onStop()`/`onDestroy()`) you have to create Service and play audio content from there.